# Why can't I add an object to the relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-and-belongs-to-many

Just learning rails...

I have the following models:

```
class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::
   has_and_belongs_to_many :time_slots
end
```

I also have a model to join the two:

```
class TimeSlotsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :time_slot_id, :user_id
end
```

In the console, I create a user object and I want to associate it with a TimeSlot. I have an variable `ts` that is a TimeSlot object, and `u` that is a user object. Both already exist in the database. When I do `ts.users << u`, I get a error saying "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: time_slots_users.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "time_slots_users" ("time_slot_id", "user_id") VALUES (1, 1).

Why would created_at be null? Isn't it being automatically created when the record in TimeSlotsUsers is created? Do I need to use a has-many through relationship instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join model is a good pattern if you want to have any information other than the user_id and timeslot_id as part of the relation ship.  For example, if you have `groups` and `users` and you have a many-to-many relationship, but sometimes a user is an `admin` of a group, you might put the `is_admin` attribute on the join model.

To keep your join model, a better Rails patter is as follows...

```
class TimeSlot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_slot_users
  has_many :users, through: :time_slot_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_slot_users
  has_many :time_slots, through: :time_slot_users
end

class TimeSlotsUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :time_slots
end
```

I disagree with one of the other answers that advocates no primary key on the join table.
To have the unique id of a relationship is important when you want to delete or edit that relationship using a REST API, for example.  Whether to have an `updated_at` or `created_at` depends on whether they are useful data in your problem domain.  It might be useful information, for example, to know when a user was added to a group (or it might not be).

It is important to have a unique index on the join table on (user_id, time_slot_id) to ensure data integrity. Rails models can validate uniqueness reliably in 99.999% of instances, but not 100% of the time.

Comment: When using `has_and_belongs_to_many` the `updated_at` and `created_at` columns don't get set by Rails. The only way to get that working is by hacking Rails or by adding triggers to your database. You might as well remove them, or at least don't make them required. Can't really determine if a `has_many :through` is what is needed here, but from the join model it seems `time_slots_users` is *really* only a join table, without any extra attributes. In that case a simple `has_and_belongs_to_many` may be enough and my answer solves the question. I agree with your other comments.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that the `updated_at` and `created_at` are not set. That makes sense. In terms of the design, right now the table is a simple join table.

Answer (score 1):

The join table for a habtm relationship [should not have `created_at` and `updated_at` columns](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has_and_belongs_to_many-associations). You also don't need the join model.

If you want to do something with the join tabel and/or add attributes to it you should change to `has_many :through`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say I don't need the join model? Is the join table not necessary?

Comment: @JeffreyGuenther: The table is necessary, but not the model.

Comment: Got it. Table must exist in the DB, but the Ruby/Rails object doesn't need to be defined.

Comment: @JeffreyGuenther: exactly. Just delete `app/models/time_slots_users.rb` and drop those two timestamp columns and you should be fine.